# org.json character encoding/decoding issue

Tags: java, json

So I have a webservice call that is giving me back a JSON string. I've requested that the response send be back the content in UTF-8 encoding. When I inspect the value returned everything looks good. It's when I create a new JSONObject and pass the JSON text into the constructor that things start to cause problems.

Specifically: 
The webservice returns with an EM DASH (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm) character in the response - "format":"On Demand Event—All Sessions"

After the JSONObject receives the string it converts this character into the java representation of this character - "format":"On Demand Event\u2014All Sessions"

I am using the org.json library to do my bidding and am considering moving to a different implementation if necessary. Here is what I've got running the show:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
GetMethod getDownloads = new GetMethod("http://localhost:8080/ecommerce-ws/service/account/downloads");

getDownloads.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, "UTF-8");
getDownloads.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

client.executeMethod(getDownloads);

String httpResponse = getDownloads.getResponseBodyAsString();

JSONObject downloadsJSON = new JSONObject(httpResponse);
```

Is there some way that I can set the character encoding on the JSONObject when it parses the string? I've done quite a bit of looking around and have found very little that helps.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

The JSON spec seems to allow escaping of all unicode chars

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

but when I test, the GSON doesn't seem to escape the EM DASH

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/